# Equivalencia de JSON

Tags: php, json

Buenas, ¿ a qué equivaldría un JSON como este pero decodeado desde PHP?.

JSON

```
{
"lists": [
    {
        "title": "do",
        "defaultStyle": "list-danger",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "beforeItemDelete is never called",
                "description": "even in your \"Event handling\" example"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "doing",
        "defaultStyle": "list-info",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "Function to get all list info (lists, items) as object"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "done",
        "defaultStyle": "list-success",
        "items": [
            {
                "title": "List style change event"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

PHP

```
// conexión

  $sql = "SELECT id, title, description, dueDate, done FROM list";

  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  $arreglo = array();

while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arreglo["lists"]["items"] = $data;
}

 echo json_encode($arreglo);


// desconexión
```

¿ Me mostraría la estructura correcta equivalente al JSON ? he printado el PHP y creo que me lo muestra correctamente, pero al no funcionarme lo que estoy haciendo como es debido, me surge esta gran duda.
Gracias !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tras conocer el esquema de la base de datos ha sido posible implementar una solución a medida:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT
    id,
    title,
    description,
    DATE_FORMAT(dueDate, '%Y-%m-%d') dueDate,
    done
  FROM todolist
";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result === false) {
  die($mysqli->error);
}
$arreglo = [
  'lists' => [
    0 => [
      'title' => 'Tareas',
      'defaultStyle' => 'list-success',
      'items' => [],
    ],
  ],
];
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  /* El título es obligatorio en el registro */
  $elemento = [
    'title' => $data['title']
  ];
  /* Si la descripción no es nula la agregamos */
  if (is_null($data['description']) === false) {
    $elemento['description'] = $data['description'];
  }
  /* Si la fecha de vencimiento no es nula la agregamos también */
  if (is_null($data['dueDate']) === false) {
    $elemento['dueDate'] = $data['dueDate'];
  }
  /* Si done es cualquier otra cosa menos un 0, la tarea está hecha */
  if ($data['done'] != 0) {
    $elemento['done'] = true;
  }
  /* Agregamos al listado el elemento que acabamos de crear */
  $arreglo["lists"][0]["items"][] = $elemento;
}
/* Enviamos al navegador la información */
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arreglo);
```

---

**Respuesta original**

Esa información se asemeja a ésta en PHP:

```
$arreglo = [
  'lists' => [
    [
      'title' => 'do',
      'defaultStyle' => 'list-danger',
      'items' => [
        [
          'title' => "beforeItemDelete is never called",
          'description' => "even in your \"Event handling\" example",
        ],
      ],
    ],
    [
      'title' => 'doing',
      'defaultStyle' => 'list-info',
      'items' => [
        [
          'title' => "Function to get all list info (lists, items) as object",
        ],
      ],
    ],
    [
      'title' => 'done',
      'defaultStyle' => 'list-success',
      'items' => [
        [
          'title' => "List style change event",
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
echo json_encode($arreglo, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Su ejecución genera el siguiente resultado:

```
{
    "lists": [
        {
            "title": "do",
            "defaultStyle": "list-danger",
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "beforeItemDelete is never called",
                    "description": "even in your \"Event handling\" example"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "doing",
            "defaultStyle": "list-info",
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "Function to get all list info (lists, items) as object"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "done",
            "defaultStyle": "list-success",
            "items": [
                {
                    "title": "List style change event"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Prueba con este código en lugar del tuyo:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, description, dueDate, done FROM list";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result === false) {
  die($mysqli->error);
}
$arreglo = [
  'lists' => [
    0 => [
      'items' => [],
    ],
  ],
];
while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arreglo["lists"][0]["items"][] = $data;
}

echo json_encode($arreglo);
```

Estamos rellenando (imagino) sólo el índice 0 del resultado, por lo que hay que agregarlo a él y no crear directamente `items` en `lists`.

Primero genero una estructura base (con el índice 0 relleno) y luego voy agregando elementos por cada resultado de la consulta SQL.

Comment: Estoy probando lo que me comentas y me tira: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean** Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Eso ya es cosa tuya, de tu código, ya que por algún motivo la consulta no se ejecuta (`$result` te vale `false`). Depura tu código de base de datos, he agregado un pequeño bloque de control para averiguar el motivo por el que falla la consulta. Ahora me cuentas.

Comment: ¿Has conseguido averiguar qué provocaba el error SQL?

Comment: Sí, disculpas, era un error ortográfico mío, funciona bien, pero no debería de decirle en que parte del array se va a insertar cada campo de la consulta ? Gracias !

Comment: Todo depende del significado de los campos de la base de datos, pero como no sé cómo debo interpretarlos (no conozco ni el esquema ni su contenido) no sé cómo meter los datos en el array de manera correcta/eficiente.

Comment: lo que me refería era que si por ejemplo yo puedo predefinir de manera manual algunos campos, como por ejemplo el primer title y defaultStyle, porque esos no me interesan que cambiar dinámicamente, he utilizado este código     **'lists' => [
      0 => [
        "title" => "do",
        "defaultStyle" => "list-danger",
        'items' => [],
      ],
    ],
  ];** no sé si estará correcto.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58470/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-cifu).